# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space running applet

Tags: java

I'm developing a graphic user interface with NetBeans IDE 7.0.1. I need to operate with long Strings (about 1 GB) and I've changed the start up configuration parameter to:

```
-J-Xss512M
-J-Xms4G
-J-Xmx12G
-J-XX:PermSize=4G
-J-XX:MaxPermSize=8G
```

When I execute the applet I receive the "`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`" exception. I've checked th point of the exception and at that moment, the applet was trying to concatenate two Strings, one of them of 550.000.000 length and the other 68.000.000
If I change the parameters above, it changes nothing on the applet exception.
My computer has 16 GB RAm so I think this is not the problem. Maybe some applet configuration?
Can you help me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Bite in the lemon, and go to other data structures. StringBuilder? Gzip bytes of compressed strings. Maybe even a database might do.

Comment: Could you add first few lines of the stack trace as well. That might help.

Comment: Where does the Netbeans profiler say your memory went (and you use a 64 bit JVM?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What operating system are you running on?  If its a 32 bit one you wont be able to address more than around 4G of RAM (less in practice, especially on a Windows machine).

The second point here is the config you're changing is, ***I think***, for NetBeans - not for the applet.  If so (and I'm not sure how this works in NetBeans) then you need to alter the memory settings for your Applet itself, not for NetBeans.

This is typically done via run configuration settings for the app/applet etc you're trying to run.

Hope this helps!